# Question about an notations about an exercises from Arbib and Manes regarding quotient vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, quotient-spaces

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes

Let $X$ be a vector space.  If $A$ is a subset of $X$, show that there is at most one vector space structure on $A$ such that the inclusion map $i:A\rightarrow X$ is linear, and that this occurs iff $A$ is a subspace of $X$.  If $E$ is an equivalence relation on $X,$ show that there is at most one vector space structure on $X/E$ such that $\eta_E:X\rightarrow X/E$ is linear and that this occurs iff $[0]$ is a subspace of $X$ (in which case, $E=\{(x,x')\mid x-x'\in [0]\})$.)

I am having trouble showing that "show that there is at most one vector space structure on $X/E$ such that $\eta_E:X\rightarrow X/E$ is linear and that this occurs iff $[0]$ is a subspace of $X$ (in which case, $E=\{(x,x')\mid x-x'\in [0]\})$.)".  I am having difficulties because I am not clear on what the notation for $E=\{(x,x')\mid x-x'\in [0]\})$ means.  Does it mean I am quotioning out all the vectors of the form $x=x'$ also, I know that $[x]\in X/E,$ so what is modding out $E$ the same as modding out $[0]$.  Finally, can I assume that $\eta_E(x)=x+E$?

Furthermore, I know that $X/X$ is the zero space, which means it consists of a single element.  For in $X/X$, $X+X=(0+X)+(0+X)=(0+0)+X=0+X=X.$  So $X$ is the null space of $X$.

Also, $x\sim x'$ iff $x-x'\in E,$ then $x\sim 0$ iff $x-0\in E$ which implies $x\in E$.  Then the coset $x+E$ is the zero element in the quotient iff $x\in E$.  This means $[0]=E$.

As to the proof that there is at most one vector space structure on $X/E$, here is the proof.

Proof:  To prove that $+$ and $\oplus$ agree, let $[y_1],[y_2]\in X/E$. Since $\eta_E$ is surjective, there exist $x_1,x_2\in X$ such that $\eta_E(x_i)=[y_i],$ for $i=1,2$ It follows that
$$[y_1]+[y_2]=\eta_E(x_1)+\eta_E(x_2)=\eta_E(x_1+x_2)=\eta_E(x_1)\oplus \eta_E(x_2)=[y_1]\oplus [y_2]$$
Hence $+=\oplus$.

To prove that $\cdot$ and $\odot$ agree, let $[y]\in X/E$ and let $\lambda\in \Bbb F$. Again because of surjectivity of $\eta_E$, there exists a $x\in X$ such that $\eta_E(x)=[y]$. It follows that
$$
\lambda\cdot [y]=\lambda\cdot \eta_E(x)=\eta_E(\lambda\cdot x)=\lambda\odot \eta_E(x)=\lambda\odot [y]
$$

This proves that $\cdot=\odot$.

Comment: Use `*text*` for *text*.

Comment: @Shaun if I use *text*, how do I incorporate LaTex code with it?  Say defining kernel of a function in set builder notation.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  You used `$\textit{text}$` instead of `*text*` for the title of the book; I made no reference to $\rm\LaTeX$ for mathematical symbols.

Comment: @Shaun oh ok ok.   That is what you were referring to.

Comment: You also should not delete substantial parts of your question after receiving answers. (Adding additional stuff at the end is fine.)

Comment: @EikeSchulte I added back all the stuff in the original post, along with fixing the proof.

Comment: Your proof is getting closer, but there is still confusion in there: $[x]$ is not an element of $X$. $[y]$ does not make sense, as $y$ is not element of $X$.

Comment: @EikeSchulte I fixed the proof.  I keep getting where $[y], x$ are elements of.

Comment: It’s fine-ish now. I still would prefer not having brackets around the $y$ anywhere. The brackets usually mean: Take the equivalence class containing this element. You seem to use them to mark variables that happen to be equivalence classes. Other than that, it’s correct.

Comment: @EikeSchulte let me try to see if I can work out some of what you say and I will added it to my post.  I will leave a comment here to let know after so that if you have time, you can look it over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you’re a bit confused, maybe because you already know what a quotient vector space is.

The first thing to note is that $E$ is not a subspace of $X$! $E$ is an equivalence relation on $X$, i.e. a subset of $X \times X$ with certain properties. In particular, it makes no sense to write $x + E$ for an element $x \in X$. This is despite the fact that we use the same notation $X/E$ that we would use for quotienting out a subspace.

I will only give hints to the actual exercise for now.

For the first part (there is at most one vector space structure), it is probably easiest to only use the fact that $\eta_E$ is surjective (you might know this as an *onto* map). That is: If $\eta : X \to Y$ is a surjective map and $X$ is a vector space, show that there is at most one vector space structure on $Y$ that makes $\eta$ into a linear map.

The “iff” in the second part is just wrong. That $[0]$ is a subspace of $X$ is not sufficient for there to be such a vector space structure on $X/E$. (Can you find a counter-example?)

However, if there is such a vector space structure, $[0]$ will be a subspace and $E$ will be of the form given in the exercise. As a first step, show that $[0]$ is the *kernel* of $\eta_E$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145155/discussion-on-answer-by-eike-schulte-question-about-an-notations-about-an-exerci); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @EikeSchulte I spoke to a friend and showed him our chat discussion.  I understand what you mean now.  Basically, you told me that in one direction, it is not possible to assume that $[0]$ is a subspace, then $n_E(x):X\rightarrow X/E$ is linear.  What you meant by if it is possible, you meant the converse direction and to show first that the $\text{ker}(n_E(x)=0.$  He explained to me what the equivalence relations $E$ means.  That two elements $x,x'$ are in $E$ iff both are send to the $[0]$ equivalence class.  When he said that, everything clicked.  Thank you for all your patience.  :)

Comment: @EthanBolker it is not the same question. This one is about show coequalizer exists in category of vector spaces, the other one is showing equalizer exists in category of vector spaces. I edited the title of both questions to show that I am asking different question in each respective post.